# AngularJS passing variable to service

Tags: angularjs, variables, service, controller, resources

I start with angularJS and I don't understant how you can push a variable from the controller to a service.
I try with $rootScope but the value of the variable was undefined

here is my service :

```
technoServices.factory('Config',['$rootScope','$resource',
  function($rootScope,$resource,token){

return $resource('../../rest/config',null,{
    get: {
        method:'GET',
        headers:{'X-Token':""+$rootScope.headers},
        isArray:false}
});
}]);
```

and here is my controller :

```
var technoControllers = angular.module('technoControllers', []);

technoControllers.controller('loginCtrl', ['$scope','$rootScope', 'Techno',function($scope,$rootScope, Techno) {
$scope.getXtoken = function (user,psw){
    $scope.config = Techno.post({username:user,password:psw},function(response,headers){
        $scope.status= response.status;
        $rootScope.headers = headers('X-Token');
        if($rootScope.headers != null){
            $scope.log = true;
        }else{
            $scope.log = false;
        }
    })};

}

  ]);

technoControllers.controller('configCtrl', ['$scope', 'Config', function($scope, Config) {

$scope.getConfig = function (){
$scope.maConfig = Config.get();

}
```

So as you can see , I need the variable from the response header of my first service in the header request of my seconde service. How can I do it ?

Answer (score 0):

You can just use another service as shared service which will have the value and inject in both the controller and service.
Code snippet would be like this.

```
technoServices.factory('Shared',
  function(){
var Shared={};
Shared.setValue=function(header){
Shared.header = header;
}
Shared.getValue=function(){
return Shared.header;
}
return Shared;
});
```

And in controller you can use as

```
technoControllers.controller('loginCtrl', ['$scope','$rootScope', 'Techno',function($scope,$rootScope, Techno, Shared) {
$scope.getXtoken = function (user,psw){
    $scope.config = Techno.post({username:user,password:psw},function(response,headers){
        $scope.status= response.status;
        Shared.setValue(headers('X-Token'));
        //$rootScope.headers = headers('X-Token');
        if($rootScope.headers != null){
            $scope.log = true;
        }else{
            $scope.log = false;
        }
    })};

}

  ]);
```

You can inject Shared service in Config to get data

```
technoServices.factory('Config',['$rootScope','$resource','Shared'
  function($rootScope,$resource,token,Shared){

return $resource('../../rest/config',null,{
    get: {
        method:'GET',
        //headers:{'X-Token':""+$rootScope.headers},
        headers:{'X-Token':""+Shared.getValue()},
        isArray:false}
});
```

}]);

Comment: I try your solution but I get this error : TypeError: Cannot call method 'getValue' of undefined

Comment: Can you check the order of services? Shared should be defined before Config.

Comment: Shared was after Config , now I defined it before but I still got the same error

Comment: Ok , the problem was the declaration of Config , my bad. Now the problem is that when I launch my application it directly do the Shared.getValue() in Config , and I want that when I launch the app it do the first service and do the Shared.setValue() and when I press a button it launch the second service , because now the header is undefined everytimes. (Hope you understand what I mean)